# Making a line with a different data format

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make some lines with this data format:

```
var data3 =  [
  { "task": "Estructura",  "data": [{"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-01-03")),"y":0}, {"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-03-09")),"y":8}] },
  { "task": "Mamposteria", "data": [{"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-02-01")),"y":0}, {"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-03-01")),"y":8}] },
  { "task": "Friso",       "data": [{"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-03-01")),"y":0}, {"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-03-30")),"y":8}] },
  { "task": "Mortero",     "data": [{"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-05-01")),"y":8}, {"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-07-01")),"y":0}] },
  { "task": "Pisos",       "data": [{"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-07-01")),"y":8}, {"x":new Date(Date.parse("2014-09-01")),"y":0}] }
];
```

And this the code for generating the lines:

```
var colors = [
  'steelblue',
  'green',
  'red',
  'purple',
  'black'
]

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([
      new Date(Date.parse('2014-01-01')),
      new Date(Date.parse('2014-12-31'))
    ])
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 8])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line() // line generator
  .interpolate("linear")
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.data.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.data.y); });      

var activities = svg.selectAll('.line')
  .data(data3)
  .enter()
  .append("path");

var activitiesAttibutes = activities
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr('stroke', function(d,i){
    return colors[i%colors.length];
  })
  .attr("d", line)
  .attr("transform", "translate(15,30)");
```

but I'm having trouble because it is not a two element array.

Do I have to arrange the data in another way or make changes in the line function generator? Could you provide me an example where I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that need to change here - you need to iterate over the `data` array in each object for the line, and you need to change the accessors so that they apply to a single object in the `data` array:

```
var line = d3.svg.line() // line generator
  .interpolate("linear")
  // d is a single object in a data array
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });
```

and then to apply the line, you're acting on a top-level object, so you need to pass in the `data` array:

```
var activitiesAttibutes = activities
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.data);
  });
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h07s5jc5/1/